# How to make Maps in iOS6 same as iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, mkmapview

I have an app where where i am using MkMapView and its showing differently for iOS6 and iOS5.
I have attached the screenShots below

iOS 6
[image]

iOS 5

[image]

Can Anyone tell me how can i solve this issue ?

Answer (score 5):

This is because IOS 5 uses google maps and IOS 6 is using apple maps,
The only thing you could do is use the google maps API on IOS 5 and on IOS6
This way they will look and work the same

[Google maps for IOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use Apple's Mapkit framework and show google maps for IOS 6.0 onwards then u can use overlays.

Here is sample project that may help you.

https://github.com/mladjan/GoogleMapsOverlayiOS/tree/master/GoogleMapsiOS6Demo

Answer (score 0):

The map display is default as per IOS installed on device or iPhone/iPad.
                If you still want to use Google map then load map in web-view with your location.